c++ exception failed in arm-none-eabi-g++
I want to use c++'s exception with arm-none-eabi-g++9.2.1 on Cortex-A9 board.
But I found that, exception could be caught but "terminate" will also be called.
To use C++ exception,
I've learned that I should do something as follows:

call __libc_init_array() when my RTOS starts up;

add some thing into linkscript:


.init_array :
{
    // some symble that __libc_init_array will use...
}

.ARM.exidx : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    __exidx_end = .;
}

After 1 and 2, I try to run C++ exception in a task of RTOS(not c++'s thread)：
// .cpp
// this is my custom exception
class MyE : public std::exception
{
    ...
}

// .cpp
// use custom exception
void myfunc(int value) {
    try {
        throw MyE();
    } catch(MyE &e) {
        printf("catch an exception\n");    // I've already implemented some stub funtions such as _write_r
    }

    printf("hello world outsize\n");
}

// .c
// test program
void app() {
    myfunc();
}

And the result is as fllows:
catch an exception
hello world outsize
terminate called without an active exception

I want to know why terminate will be called, it seems the exception is caught successfully, but terminate was still called.
What shoud I do?

Check the assembly listing and see if stack unwinding is being handled properly.

Where is your toolchain from? A very popular one used to be compiled without exceptions.
Also, is this even exception-related? I mean: does the void app(); keep spinning inside the loop, or maybe it exits and hits terminate at the end (for whatever reason)?
